# Resetting a "No Results Found" function after search is completed

Tags: angular, typescript

After some trial and error I have a working Angular2 search feature, that also prints "No Results Found" to the screen in the instance where no results are found to match a user's query. My last challenge is to re-set the field so the next time the user goes to the search field the "No Results Found" is cleared. In other words, as soon as the user exists the search field it should reset. So far what I've tried doesn't work. When the user clicks out of the search field, and then clicks back in, the "No Results Found" text is still being printed to the screen from the last instance. This is what I'm using to handle the printing to the screen of "No Results Found":

```
public get noResultsFound(): boolean
{
    if (!Object.isNullOrUndefined(this._results) && this._results.length < 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (Object.isNullOrUndefined(this.query)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in my view I have the following:

```
<div class="field-container">
    <i *ngIf="isSearchIconVisible" class="material-icons search-icon">search</i>
    <auto-complete-field
            class="auto-complete-field"
            #autoCompleteField
            (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
            (focus)="onFocus()"
            (blur)="onBlur()"
            [(value)]="query"
            [(options)]="__autoCompleteSuggestions">Loading...
    </auto-complete-field>
    <div *ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound" class="no-results-found">No Results Found</div>
</div>
```

Comment: noResultsFound is a method, not a property from your component model! *ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound" should be *ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound()"

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're saying, I'd suggest handling this as part of your `onBlur()`. So instead of:

`*ngIf="inputHasFocus && noResultsFound"`

something like:

`<div *ngIf="showNoResults" class="no-results-found">No Results Found</div>`

Then in your controller, set `showNoResults` to `true` when `noResultFound()` returns true, and set it to false in `onBlur()`

Comment: If you mean doing this:

    `public get showNoResults(): boolean
    {
        if (this.noResultsFound) {
            return true;
        } else if (this.onBlur) {
            return false;
        }
    }`

And then, in the view, this:

`<div *ngIf="showNoResults" class="no-results-found">No Results Found</div>`

I tried it, but, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: `public get noResultsFound(): boolean
{
    if (!Object.isNullOrUndefined(this._results) && this._results.length < 1) {
        this.showNoResults = true;
        return true;
    } else if (Object.isNullOrUndefined(this.query)) {
        return false;
    }
}`

And

`onBlur() { this.showNoResults = false; }`

Comment: When I try this I get an error: "Property 'showNoResults' does not exist on type 'SearchField'.

Comment: It's occurring to me that maybe the way to handle this is on the search function itself. If that re-sets, then the "No Results Found" should be cleared along with it.

Comment: Except that wouldn't give you the behavior of the 'No Results' message clearing when the search input loses focus.

Comment: Re: the error you were getting. You also need to add `showNoResults` to the model. Put this above the constructor: `public showNoResults: boolean`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128750/discussion-between-bkd-and-amuramoto).

Comment: So I tried this according to what you posted: 

public get noResultsFound(): boolean 
{ if (!Object.isNullOrUndefined(this._results) && this._results.length < 1) { 
this.showNoResults = true; 
return true; 
} else if (Object.isNullOrUndefined(this.query)) { 
return false; 
} 
} 

And then re: the onBlur(), I have this: 

private onBlur(): void 
{ 
this.showNoResults = false; 
} 

But the behavior is the same as far as I can tell. Any ideas?